# jQuery loop with wildcard

Tags: jquery, loops, wildcard

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8KJTn/)

I'm having some html markup with uls. Whenever the user clicks on a link with the class vid_* (* as something) the ul with that id should be shown. When I use loops without wildcards, the following works:

```
$(".vid_all").click(function () {
    $("#vid_bla").addClass("hidden").removeClass("visible");
    $("#vid_muh").addClass("hidden").removeClass("visible");
    $("#vid_tschub").addClass("hidden").removeClass("visible");
});

$(".vid_bla").click(function () {
    $("#vid_bla").addClass("visible").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#vid_muh").addClass("hidden").removeClass("visible");
    $("#vid_tschub").addClass("hidden").removeClass("visible");
});

$(".vid_muh").click(function () {
    $("#vid_muh").addClass("visible").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#vid_bla").addClass("hidden").removeClass("visible");
    $("#vid_tschub").addClass("hidden").removeClass("visible");
});

$(".vid_tschub").click(function () {
    $("#vid_tschub").addClass("visible").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#vid_bla").addClass("hidden").removeClass("visible");
    $("#vid_muh").addClass("hidden").removeClass("visible");
});
```

Now I want to use wildcards instead in order to handle the loops dynamically and shorten it a bit.

I tried the following but it is not working:

```
var vidRnd = /(.vid_*)/;
var arrVidId = new Array("#vid_plattform", "#vid_format", "#vid_bro");

for (var k in vidRnd) {

    $(k).click(function() {
        for (var i in arrVidId) {
            $(i).addClass("hidden").removeClass("visible");
        }
        $(k).addClass("visible").removeClass("hidden");
    });
};
```

I want to use wildcards for the array too but I dont know how to. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following jquery

```
var vidRnd = new Array(".vid_all", ".vid_bla", ".vid_muh", ".vid_tschub")
var arrVidId = new Array("#vid_bla", "#vid_muh", "#vid_tschub");
$.each(vidRnd, function( index, k ) {
$(k).click(function () {
    for (var i in arrVidId) {
        $(i).addClass("hidden").removeClass("visible");
    }
    $(k).addClass("visible").removeClass("hidden");
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not "shorter" than your code but it works with any number of categories as long as the `class` (and the corresponding `id`) starts with `vid_` and is the **last** class in the list.

```
$("ul.vidkategorie").on("click", "a", function (ev) {
    var classNames = this.className.split(/\s+/),
        selectedClass = classNames[classNames.length - 1];

    if (selectedClass) {
        // hide all lists
        $("ul.vidkat_follow").addClass("hidden");

        // show the selected one (or all)
        if (selectedClass == "vid_alle") {
            $("ul[id^=vid_]").removeClass("hidden");
        } else {
            $("#" + selectedClass).removeClass("hidden");
        }
    }

    // prevent the browser from following the link
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6H6NF/)

Answer (score 0):

By changing the href attributes in the All Category to point to the relevant category you could use an approach like this:

Markup

```
<ul class="vidkategorie vidkat_first">
 <li><a class="vid_active vid_link" href="#vid_alle">All</a></li>
 <li><a class="vid_inactive vid_link" href="#vid_bla">Category 1</a></li>
 <li><a class="vid_inactive vid_link " href="#vid_muh">Category 2</a></li>
 <li><a class="vid_inactive vid_link " href="#vid_tschub">Category 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$('.vidkat_first a').click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var target= $(this).attr('href');
  if( target=="#vid_alle") {
    $('.vidkat_follow').show();
  }
  else {
    $('.vidkat_follow').hide();
    $(target).show();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to toggle the information below a link, right?
To do this for all elements which do have the same markup, you can use jquery's context feature within the selector.
And you might want to restructure your markup to support parent/child selectors.

If you markup looks like this for example:

```
<a class="toggleAll">Toggle all</a>
<div class="item">
    <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
    <ul class="info">
        <li>lala</li>
        <li>blub</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
    <ul class="info">
        <li>lala</li>
        <li>blub</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The JavaScript to toggle all and toggle one element when the user clicks the link is pretty simple:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".toggleAll").click(function () {
      $(".info").toggle();
   });
   $(".item .link").click(function (e) {
      $(".info", $(this).parent()).toggle();
   });
});
```

So this should really simplify your code a lot, it just depends on how you structure your markup.
Of cause instead of class names you can also use IDs or names or whatever to identify your items.

:edit:
To goggle all other items and to have a default state on page load you can modify the script like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".hideAll").click(function () {
    $(".info").hide();
});
$(".showAll").click(function () {
    $(".info").show();
});
$(".item .link").click(function (e) {
    var currentInfo = $(".info", $(this).parent());
    $(".info").not(currentInfo).hide();
    $(currentInfo).show(100);
});
$(".info").hide();
$(".info").first().show();
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Didn't recognized the fiddle link in the first place, here is a solution which is flexible enough to extend it easily

```
$(".vid_alle",".vidkat_first").click(function () {
    $(".vidkat_follow").show();
});
$(".vid_link", ".vidkat_first").not(".vid_alle").click(function () {
    $(".vidkat_follow").hide();
    var catLink = this;
    $(".vidkat_follow").each(function(index, elem){
        if ($(catLink).hasClass(elem.id)) {
            $(elem).show();
        }
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vLUZF/1/